# IDisposable created inside Linq - Exception Safety

Tags: c#, .net, linq, idisposable

I have something similar to the following setup:

```
class DisposableContainer : IDisposable
{
  IEnumerable<DisposableObject> items;

  //Potential problem method
  public void Populate(IEnumerable<OtherThings> things)
  {
    items = things.Select(thing => new DisposableObject(thing)); 
  }

  //IDisposable Implementation
  private bool disposed = false;
  ~DisposableContainer()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  public override void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  private void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!disposed)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        if (items != null)
        {
          items.Select(item => item.Dispose());
        }
      }

      disposed = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Assume that `DisposableObject` implements `IDisposable` properly, and has a constructor that accepts parameter of type `OtherThing`.

Suppose while in the `Populate` method, if the 3rd iteration of the select call throws an exception, what happens to the first two `DisposableObject`s created successfully? I'm assuming they get leaked and remain undisposed.

Follow up question: Is there a way to safely handle the above scenario while still using Linq to generate the `IEnumerable<>`?  I cannot foresee one, but I wanted to toss out the idea to see if anyone else had a thought.

Comment: Your `Select` query will not ever be executed if you don't use a immediate execution operation like `ToArray`. Also, you shouldn't cause side-effects like this inside a Linq query.

Comment: `items.Select(item => item.Dispose());` is terrible practice. Use a foreach loop and wrap the dispose in a try catch in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: `items.Select(...)` could be instead `items.ForEach(...)`

Comment: @RufusL Ah really? I was looking for one of those... Thanks.

Comment: @Serge @RufusL `ForEach` is not a part of Linq. You can implement it yourself or use `MoreLinq`. In any case, this can't exactly replace `Select` since it doesn't return any values. It's only used to shorten a regular `foreach`.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - Microsoft's Reactive Framework team have an excellent object that pretty much does what you want - `CompositeDisposable`. Just Nuget "Rx-Main" and look for that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Already created `DisposableObject`s would not be disposed properly.

You can fix it by using a temporary list that holds the created items, and disposing them if needed:

```
public void Populate(IEnumerable<OtherThings> things)
{
    var temp = new List<DisposableObject>();
    try
    {
        temp.AddRange(things.Select(otherThing => new DisposableObject(otherThing)));
        items = temp;
    }
    catch
    {
        foreach (var disposableObject in temp)
        {
            disposableObject.Dispose();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

This can't be done by using the existing Linq extension methods, however you *can* (and this isn't a recommendation to do so) add an extension method of your own:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<TDisposable> SelectDisposables<TItem, TDisposable>(
    this IEnumerable<TItem> enumerable, 
    Func<TItem,TDisposable> selector)
    where TItem : IDisposable
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    var temp = new List<TDisposable>();
    try
    {
        temp.AddRange(enumerable.Select(selector));
        return temp;
    }
    catch
    {
        foreach (var disposable in temp)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
items = things.SelectDisposables(thing => new DisposableObject(thing));
```